# PDO fetchAll seems to fail when result has single row?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm stumped. Consider the following test table:

```
----------------
| art_projects |
----------------------------------
| project_name | project_creator |
|--------------|-----------------|
| Flying Feet  | 1               |
| Dinosaurs    | 2               |
| Roadblock    | 1               |
----------------------------------
```

Paired with it, consider the following code (where `$db` is a confirmed-functional PDO instance):

```
$dbObj = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM art_projects WHERE project_creator = ?");
$dbObj->execute([1]);
print_r($dbObj->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Very simple, very little can go wrong. This functions as expected and returns the following  result set:

```
----------------------------------
| project_name | project_creator |
|--------------|-----------------|
| Flying Feet  | 1               |
| Roadblock    | 1               |
----------------------------------
```

Here's where the problem starts. If I change the `execute()` to search for ID 2 instead of 1, I'd expect it would return a single-row result for `Dinosaurs`. It doesn't - I get this instead:

```
1
```

When I change `$dbObj->fetchAll(...)` to `$dbObj->fetch(...)`, though, I get the expected single-row result. The heck...?

---

Now, I'm pretty new to PDO, but I'm assuming this is expected behavior; I can't seem to find anything about this being an "error", here or elsewhere on Google. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Furthermore, is there an accepted/effective method to deal with this? IMHO, It's kind of a Catch-22 to test the length of the result set for the sake of using the right fetch method, and it's unreasonable to magically know when your result set is going to be single-row or multiple-row.

Comment: I also welcome any relevant criticism, as there's a chance I could just be doing things very, very wrong.

Comment: I could be wrong but I generally do not pass parameters in [brackets] like that. Try double quotes or single quotes.  $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array('xxxxxxx','xxxxx',$product_code));

Comment: @Waragi: nothing wrong with it. it's a perfectly valid shortcut notation for an array. It won't work on older PHP's, but that's someone else's problem.

Comment: @MarcB That's interesting, I'll have to play around with that one.

Comment: @CodeMoose: can't see why it wouldn't work. it should fetch anything available. e.g. an empty set, 1 row, 50 kajillion rows. maybe it is something else. try a simple `select 1` query to force a different result and see what happens there. eliminate the binding and actual table stuff, just fetch a fixed value and see if that comes through.

Comment: @MarcB fixed values seem to come through without issue - with and without the binding. Maybe it's got something to do with the db itself in that case? It's a near-vanilla mysql build, but it was manually compiled.

Answer (score 1):

`FETCH_ASSOC` isn't a valid documented mode for [`PDO::FetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). When it gets more than one result set row it's probably doing some sort of filling in of an associative array that wipes out the contents.

If I were you I'd loop and do the ordinary `fetch()` call once per row.

Comment: PDOStatement::fetchAll() defaults to the value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, which has a valid value of PDO::FETCH_ASSOC. Thus, it is documented (in a round-about way), and from personal experience this works. Anyway, even if you are correct with multi-row results wiping out the previous row, the asker stated it works for a two-row resultset, and NOT for a one-row resultset.